# how to completely remove Visual studio code from MacBook Pro

Tags: visual-studio-code

I downloaded and installed the latest version and used it for a few weeks. I the process of learning how it worked, I loaded several extensions. Explored they and then uninstalled them. At the end of this nothing seamed to work as it should, the natural thing for me was to uninstall and then reinstall. directions I read said to goto the applications folder, locate visual studio code app and move it to trash. Which I did. Shut down and restarted the machine. Went back to the website and downloaded and installed another copy for MAC. When installed it was the exact version as before with all the sites, code and extensions as before.

I have tried every thing I know to get a totally fresh copy installed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall), you should:

> macOS - Delete `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code` and `~/.vscode`.

to remove any and all user settings after you uninstall VSCode itself.

Comment: now it does not show up in applications or anywhere else. If I download and instal again, it runs, looks the same, but if I exit, shutdown and remove it from task bar. It is no where to be found.

Comment: So you 1. deleted VSCode from `Applications`, 2. did the above step in my answer, and now if you re-install, it's not a fresh copy and all the extensions are still there?

Comment: I went thru each step and searched for code and .vscode and could not find them. I downloaded the app again and this time moved the downloaded file to the applications directory. Then double click it and ran the program. To my surprise I have a clean copy running and is shows in the application launchpad.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: The person who asked a question on StackOverflow can "accept" an answer as the correct one. This helps future readers easily identify what is the correct solution to the problem they are looking for.